# Including required files on AJAX requested PHP page

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Recently I started learning how to set up a MVC model. I built a simple single page application to develop my skills. It requires a config files as well as some classes (using __autoload) which are all included in the index file.

My question: Suppose I want to include AJAX calls to the PHP pages which also need the aforementioned config data and/or classes to generate their output. I presume I'd have to include the required files on each and every AJAX requested PHP page, or might there be another way to take care of that "globally"?

Many thanks for your support.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Basically Ajax will call some path, one of your PHP scripts from the client, as if a browser request was made, treat it as such. You don't need to take your "config" over to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you need config for your ajax calls.

ajax is just the same path calling as other normal calls but just asynchron.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/path/", // or "yourphpfile.php"
   type: "get", // or post
   data: {data:data}
}).done(function(){
   alert("success, you are happy");
});
```

you dont need any config

Comment: True. So, any 'config'/classes needed in yourphpfile.php and any other AJAX called pages must be included using require('/path'/). I just wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: @DurianNangka, yes, but this is not ajax issue. rather php issue. whether you call the page thru ajax or normally, you need that config, if you are talking about importing some files into phpfile.